# Create lists with java

Tags: java, collections

I am very new in java. I  want to create a kind of complex array. I think its called list/collection/map...

My data looks like

```
-item
   ref:GH987
   size:22
   date:1992
-item
   ref:98KJ
   size:27
   date:2000
-item
   ref:ZXJ212
   size:24
   date:1999
```

I do not prefer to create an item Class and store the 3 instance in an array.
I found something called Map but it really confused me and I don't understand how could I access the values after creating the data. Could you help me how to start with this ?

```
final Map<String, List<String>> data = new LinkedHashMap<String, List<String>>();
data.put("item", new LinkedList<String>());
```

Comment: _I do not prefer to create an item Class and store the 3 instance in an array._ Why not? What is `-item` in your snippet? Is that a key? If it is, how do you expect the `Map` to work with duplicate keys? Is it just a label for the type of information?

Comment: Read this http://beginnersbook.com/java-collections-tutorials/ the section on Maps lists the different types. A map is basically a collection of <Key, Value> pairs. If you don't care about the order of your elements you can go with a HashMap. There are examples there on how to store and get elements

Comment: You should create an item class. After that you can use either a list or map  depending upon your need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *have to* create an `Item` class, that's the whole point of OOP!

Very minimal example:

```
public class Item {
    public String ref;
    public int size;
    public int date;
    public Item(String ref, int size, int date) {
        this.ref = ref;
        this.size = size;
        this.date = date;
    }
}
```

Then it's just a `List<Item>` and you can access each part with `myList.get(i).ref` etc:

```
List<Item> l = new ArrayList<>();
l.add(new Item("GH987", 22, 1992));
l.add(new Item("98KJ", 27, 2000));
...
for (Item it : l)
    System.out.println("Ref: "+item.ref+", size: "+item.size+", date: "+item.date);
```

Now, if you *really* want to use a `Map` to store each attribute, you have to think what would be your *unique key*. Let's suppose it's `ref`, which is a `String`:

```
Map<String,Integer> sizes = new LinkedHashMap<>(); // LinkedHashMap keeps the insert order
Map<String,Integer> dates = new LinkedHashMap<>();

sizes.put("GH987", 22);
dates.put("GH987", 1992);
sizes.put("98KJ", 27);
dates.put("98KJ", 2000);
```

then it's difficult to access all members as they're not bundled in a single instance:

```
String ref = "GH987";
System.out.println("Ref: "+ref+", size: "+sizes.get(ref)+", date: "+dates.get(ref))
```

Here you should realize that if a `Map` hasn't been updated, it will return `null` on the value and you'll have to handle consistency yourself. It is also a pain to create so many objects just to store single attributes, which in your case are `Number` subclasses (e.g. `Integer`) instead of native types, which are far more efficient.

So do yourself a favor, and create your `Item` class. Then you can use a `Map` to quickly access a particular item based on its key, which looks like the `ref` member:

```
myMap.put(ref, new Item(ref, size, date));
Item it = myMap.get(ref);
...
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes you can choose Map with a class and having it's reference as a key for ex

```
Map<String,Item> map = new HashMap<>();
```

Assuming reference is unique. You can store values like

```
map.put(item.getReference(),item);
```